# How to create sub folder in the parent folder in office 365

Tags: php, api, office365

I created a sub folder in the inbox, but I haven't created a sub folder for the new parent folder. I tried to set permission and run my code it's not use.

eg :

URL:https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/MailFolders/voicemail/childfolders

```
Voicemail -parent folder,I tried  to create a subfolder like inbound folder.
```

It showed error :

> "error":{"code":"ErrorFolderNotFound","message":"The specified folder
>   could not be found in the store."}.

How to set permission for creating sub folder in the parent folder using Rest API,PHP ?

Comment: I got answer ,Get parent folder id replace with parent folder name 

for example ,

replaced voicemail name into voicemail id.

URL:https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/MailFolders/voicemail/childfolders

into:

URL:https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/MailFolders/AAAAABB9A1QJ8SGQIcKP8uGqFSRA/childfolders